# concave function in context of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

Consider $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} $ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $(AA^T)^{-1}$
is assumed to exist.
Define $f(x)= -xAA^T x$

Why is $f$ a concave function?

Computing the hessian matrix yields: $ -AA^T$. At this point I cannot say anything about definiteness. Is there an alternative way of approaching this?

Comment: $AA^T$ is always PSD.

Comment: I see: Since $(xA)(xA)^T = || xA||_2 \geq0$

Comment: But do I get strictly concavity?

Comment: Diagonalise $AA^T$.

Comment: $AA^T = UDU^{-1}$

Comment: What does this help?